# Documentation for Navigator.NavigationBar in React Native

Tags: react-native

Most articles that i found use Navigator.NavigationBar. But i can't find any documentations for the component. Is Navigator.NavigationBar is deprecated or what ?

Answer (score 0):

[Navigator.NavigationBar](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#navigationbar) is what you are referring to??

Comment: Yeah navigationBar is prop that we need to provide a component as bar that persists across scene transitions. But Navigator.NavigationBar itself is a component.

Comment: please take a look at following snippet:

`
<Navigator
        initialRoute={...}
        renderScene={...}
        navigationBar={
          <Navigator.NavigationBar
            routeMapper={...}
          />
        }
      />
`

Comment: Did you take a look to the UIExplorer examples from React Native official repo? https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/UIExplorer/Navigator

Comment: Thank you for pointing that. But i need to know the official documentation for all props of NavigationBar.